# emotion css is overwritten by semantic ui react

Tags: semantic-ui, emotion

I  use `semantic-ui-react` and `emotion` in a `create-react-app` app.

My emotion css gets overwritten, e.g. the below semantic-ui Item color is the default semantic one.
The emotion class is created but the semantic one is in a higher priority. How can I change that (ecxcept writing `!important` all the time)?

```
        <Item
          className={css`
            background-color: #333333;
            &:hover {
              background-color: #e5e5e5;
            }
          `}
        >
```

Comment: I haven't tested this but try using `&&` or `&&&` instead of `&`